# what will happen if scanf accept more characters than there is room for in the buffer?

Tags: c

what will happen if scanf accepts more characters than there is room for in the buffer?
For example,

```
char foo[2], bar[5]="abcd";
sscanf(bar, "%s", foo);
```

Comment: Then you trigger undefined behavior

Comment: In practice, do `sscanf(bar, "%1s", foo);` and read [sscanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) and [errnno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: And ... to prevent **UB** you can limit the number of bytes scanf processes: `sscanf(bar, "%1s", foo);` which reads at most `1` byte and adds the `'\0'`

Comment: It is generally agreed that you should expect demons to come flying from your nose.

Comment: When you're reading user input, you never want to use small arrays like `[2]` or `[5]` anyway.  You never know how much the user is going to type, so you should always allocate plenty-big arrays like `[50]` or `[100]`.  Then, if you want to make sure the arrays don't overflow when you call `scanf`, use `%.49s` or `%.99s`.

Comment: Most likely however, if that happens and is noticed, you will be asked why you did not prevent it, by using alternatives to scanf() or by using it appropriatly. Compare http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be an undefined behavior as @Mad Physicist mentioned in the command but if you want to avoid I, you can use the `width` modifier of `scanf()` function to read the exact size from the buffer.

Read by 1 less than the size of the buffer to leave space for the the null character.

The example:

```
char buff[8], str[32]="asdfasdfasasdfasdfdfasdf";
sscanf(buff, "%7s", str);
```